# Pandas: drop observations that dont make up a full quarter

Tags: python, pandas

Say I have the following DataFrame, which includes monthly observations of the series "X"

```
df = pd.DataFrame({"Date":["201501", "201502", "201503", "201504", "201505", "201506", 
                           "201507", "201508", "201509", "201510", "201511", "201512"],
                           "X":[np.nan, np.nan, 100, 101,102,101, np.nan, 104, 103, 104, 
                                107, 110]}).set_index("Date")

In [32]:df
Out[32]: 
            X
Date         
201501    NaN
201502    NaN
201503  100.0
201504  101.0
201505  102.0
201506  101.0
201507    NaN
201508  104.0
201509  103.0
201510  104.0
201511  107.0
201512  110.0
```

What I need is to drop any monthly observation that isn't apart of a full quarter of data. The quarters are Q1=M1, M2, M3, Q2 = M4, M5, M6, Q3=M7, M8, M9, Q4 = M10, M11, M12

In the above example, I need the final DataFrame to be:

```
In [32]:df
Out[34]: 
             X
Date          
201501     NaN
201502     NaN
201503     NaN
201504   101.0
201505   102.0
201506   101.0
201507     NaN
201508     NaN
201509     NaN
201510   104.0
201511   107.0
201512  110.0
```

Any help? I've found a way to do what I need if the missing observations are on the ends of the dataframe, but i'm stuck on how to deal with the missing values in the middle.

Comment: The first think that come to my mind is to re-index the data frame, and set a convenient boolean condition on it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can resample and count the ones that are not NaN, and select based on that condition:

```
df[df.resample('Q').transform('count') == 3]
Out: 
                X
Date             
2015-01-01    NaN
2015-02-01    NaN
2015-03-01    NaN
2015-04-01  101.0
2015-05-01  102.0
2015-06-01  101.0
2015-07-01    NaN
2015-08-01    NaN
2015-09-01    NaN
2015-10-01  104.0
2015-11-01  107.0
2015-12-01  110.0
```

This assumes index is a datetime index. You can convert with `df.index = pd.to_datetime(df.index, format='%Y%m')`.

Answer (score 1):

Another option, you can create a group variable by converting the index to a quarter period and then check for each group if there is any missing values based on which create a logical vector for subsetting:

```
index = (df.groupby(pd.to_datetime(df.index, format = "%Y%m").to_period("Q"))
           .transform(lambda g: g.isnull().any()).X)

df.loc[index, "X"] = np.nan

df
#         X
#Date   
#201501   NaN
#201502   NaN
#201503   NaN
#201504 101.0
#201505 102.0
#201506 101.0
#201507   NaN
#201508   NaN
#201509   NaN
#201510 104.0
#201511 107.0
#201512 110.0
```